# Laravel 5.8 / VueJs 2 / Axios GET request does not send cookies (CORS, subdomain)

Tags: laravel, cookies, axios, cross-domain, subdomain

#### Setup

We have a server with the domain `test.de` and two applications `A` and `B` running on the same server but on subdomains:

```
a.test.de
b.test.de
```

#### Problem

`A` sends a `GET`-request to `B`'s API, but it's always sending the request without cookies, even though it should.

Because the endpoint is protected, we always get `401 Unauthorized` back. Requests to unprotected endpoints on `B` cause no issues, because they don't need the cookies.

#### Things we have tried:

- `withCredentials: true` on the request
- `withCredentials` set to true on axios defaults
- `laravel-cors` package configured as loose as possible

```
<?php

return [
    'supportsCredentials' => true,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];
```

- the `same_site` setting in `config/session.php` is `null`
- the `SESSION_DOMAIN` on both applications is set to `.test.de`
- middleware that sets the cors header (like laravel-cors should)
- tested on Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox
- requests to protected endpoint within a site (so A->A or B->B) work, because cookies are sent
- we tried many more things that I can't remember but will keep adding if they pop up or are mentioned in comments

Comment: Have you tried a middleware? I could put you one in the answers if you want

Comment: What kind of middleware do you mean? We have a few in place, but none related to the question.

Comment: One adding the headers... (like the laravel-cors package should)

Comment: This is really weird. A few things to try from the top of my head: 1. "test.de" as domain instead of ".test.de" 2. Try a different browser and see if it works there. 3. If that doesn't help, post the Chrome DevTools cookies screenshot, maybe something is wrong on the cookies themselves (wrong date? wrong time on the computer?)

Comment: Thanks @PavelLint, we tested different browsers. From what I've read it should be `.test.de`, but I will try. The cookies are set correctly as it works with protected routes on the application itself, but not other applications (I guess due to CORS).

Comment: also you could try disabling the CORS middleware completely to see how it goes

Comment: You mean comment out the laravel-cors and my custom middleware for CORS?

Comment: Yes, do that. Check if it works without laravel-cors and custom middleware. If it does, you know where to search.

Comment: Same issue, no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems we had permission issues on our server which prevented the frontend code from updating and therefore the `withCredentials` option was not going through.

Whoever has this issue in the future: Please read the question and you will see the things we have tried. It's important to understand that for CORS certain Headers need to be sent back and forth in order to allow cookies to be sent.

Sorry for the buzz....

Answer (score 0):

Try the middleware below... If it doesn't help I'll delete the answer ;)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

class ModifyHeadersMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next( $request );
        if($response instanceof StreamedResponse) {
            $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );
            $response->headers->set( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Application' );
            $response->headers->set( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS' );
        } else {
            $response->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );
            $response->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Application' );
            $response->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS' );
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't send any cookies.